# Is there a given fixed constellation starting point for various astrological bodies to calculate their position from for any day?

Tags: the-dark-eye

I might need to calculate the position/phase of various astrological items for my TDE troupe in the year 1013 Bosparans Fall... and while I know some of their cycle times<sup>DSA2 - Enzyclopaedia Aventurica p55</sup> and at least the calculations for Mada are given in the eternal calender perfectly \$(\text{Day}+30*(\text{Month}-1)+\text{Year}_\text{Hal}\mod{28} = 0(\text{New}))\$. Yet I lack starting points for some of the other planets and constellations.

However, I remember that there was a tool to calculate the astrological data for any given day at some point: Is there a publisched point or constellation from which one can calculate forward/backwards and where is it noted?

Comment: TDE has its own  stars.

Comment: Are the constellations important in the game? Because you'd think they'd have this information written down somewhere important. Or is it just a flavor thing for you?

Comment: @Erik It is important enough to research it for prophecy, daemonlogy, ritual magic and some uses of alchemy. I vaguely remember the G7 had lots of starbound stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### YES

It is hidden in the Maps booklet that was part of old DSA 2 Box named "Das Land des Schwarzen Auges". This one also contained the Encyclopaedia Aventurica: It has a whole sky map of the northern sky for the 1st Praios of the year 12 after Hal - or 1005 after Bosparans Fall.

Since everything rotates around the north star with the given periods a nightsky can be calculated.

### And one of these was it I remembered...

The automation of the sky calculations was undertaken (at least) twice by fans:

- once by Andreas Nortmann in 2001, who made the *[Simulation of the aventurian nightly sky](https://www.orkenspalter.de/filebase/index.php?file/136-simulation-des-aventurischen-sternenhimmels/)*, still available via orkenspalter.de but the installer fails on 64bit systems. It had also automated the calculations for summoning based on constellations.
- once by Denny Vrandecic in 2008, who made *[Niobaras Foliant](https://www.orkenspalter.de/filebase/index.php?file/137-niobaras-foliant/)*, still available via orkenspalter.de, and working under newer 64bit sytems.

Both work well before the Borbarad Campaign, which messed up the nightsky and contains specific constellations for some dates.

Comment: Unless you mean something else, 32-bit Windows executables operate fine on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie For *some* reason, the installer you get from the website says "the program can't be executed, call the maker"

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Some old installers cut corners at the time and now won’t work on modern systems.